# How to automatically mount a samba drive on boot?

Tags: debian, mount, pi-2, samba

I have this in my /etc/fstab

```
//192.168.1.1/S_Drive /mnt/readyshare cifs sec=ntlmv2,username=XXXX,password=XXXXX,uid=1000,gid=1000,iocharset=utf8 0 0
```

everytime I reboot the pi2, it says

```
[FAILED] failed to mount /mnt/readyshare
```

Here is the log

```
systemctl status mnt-readyshare.mount
mnt-readyshare.mount - /mnt/readyshare
Loaded: loaded (/etc/fstab)
Active: active (mounted) (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2015-04-28 22:42:26 CDT; 5min ago
Where: /mnt/readyshare
What: //192.168.1.1/S_Drive
Docs: man:fstab(5)
man:systemd-fstab-generator(8)
Process: 221 ExecMount=/bin/mount -n //192.168.1.1/S_Drive /mnt/readyshare -t cifs -o sec=ntlmv2,username=XXXX,password=XXXXX,uid=1000,gid=1000,iocharset=utf8 (code=exited, status=32)
```

If i run this command manually, I can mount the drive but I want to auto mount it on startup

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o sec=ntlm,username=XXXXXX,password=XXXXXXX//192.168.1.1/S_Drive /mnt/readyshare
```

Any idea why?

Comment: If you're using systemd, please provide proper logging output for the unit. Also, that unit says "Active: active (mounted)" - have you checked if that's true?

Answer (score 4):

Here's how I did it yesterday on Raspbian:

1. Create a directory /etc/samba/credentials
2. Create a file /etc/samba/credentials/myserver
3. In the myserver file, put the credentials for that server:

```
username=myusername
password=mypassword
```

Note: spaces are important here – don’t use " = ", use "=".

```
# chown -R root.root /etc/samba/credentials
# chmod 700 /etc/samba/credentials
# chmod 600 /etc/samba/credentials/myserver
```

Once this is done, you can add lines for each mount of that server to your /etc/fstab:

```
//myserver/music        /music  cifs   credentials=/etc/samba/credentials/myserver 0 0
//myserver/shared       /shared cifs   credentials=/etc/samba/credentials/myserver 0 0
```

Note that the file in /etc/samba/credentials doesn't have to be named the same thing as the server name – it just makes it easier. I created mount points for /music and /shared before I did this.